# Can't find options to open and close the optical drive/tray on HP Probook 445 G1

Tags: cd-drive, optical

I have to install some software on my laptop. I tried to open optical (CD drive) on my laptop which has Ubuntu 12.04 LTS OS on it, but I couldn't find a way.

Answer (score -3):

Buddy, It does not contain optical drive. It's just a slot, its blank from inside.
If you want to install any software from Optical disk, Get an external DVD Writer, or use Flash Drive.
I have the same from Delhi University (INDIA).

Comment: This does not appear to be correct. [HP ProBook 445 G1 Notebook PC - Specifications](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03769565) lists the machine as [having an optical drive](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03769565#AbT5).